# Replace multiple occurrences in string

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to replace all occurrences of double quotes with single quotes.
But only in the img tag! I have a html text

```
<p>First p</p><img class="image" src="one.jpg" />
<p>Second p</p><img class="image" src="two.jpg" />
```

How can I replace this "in place".
I tried something like this:

```
re.sub('"', "'", re.findall(r'<img.*/>', html))
```

The expected result is this:

```
<p>First p</p><img class='image' src='one.jpg' />
<p>Second p</p><img class='image' src='two.jpg' />
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Assuming that the html tags are a `str` type, you can use s.replace("\"", "\'"))

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2142055). Use a real HTML parser.

Comment: @Goyo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634363/replace-double-quotes-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

re.findall() returns a list, while re.sub() expects a string as the input

```
r=re.findall(r'<img.*>', html)
b=[re.sub('"', "'",a) for a in r]
for i in range(len(b)):
    html=str.replace(html,r[i],b[i])
print html
```

**Output**

```
<p>First p</p><img class='image' src='one.jpg' />
<p>Second p</p><img class='image' src='two.jpg' />
```