# Replace double quotes with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
<p>First p</p>
<p></p>
<p>"Second" p</p>
<p> </p>
<p><img class="image" src="image.jpg" /></p>
<p> </p>
<p><img class="image" src="second.jpg" /></p>
```

I use BeautifulSoup as a html parser.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
imgs = soup.findAll("img")
for img in imgs:
    # replace double quotes with single quotes            
return soup.prettify()
```

How can I replace the double quotes with single quotes (only in the img tags)?
The expected result is this:

```
<p>First p</p>
<p></p>
<p>"Second" p</p>
<p> </p>
<p><img class='image' src='image.jpg' /></p>
<p> </p>
<p><img class='image' src='second.jpg' /></p>
```

Comment: @Arman, so, you have a solution?

Comment: @Arman, so, good for all